# Outlook Web-Add-In: Execute Function hangs

Tags: javascript, command, manifest, ribbon, outlook-web-addins

I am currently developing an Outlook Web-Add-In, which executes a JavaScript function when a button in the ribbon is clicked. Another button which shows the Task Pane works.

The first button does not execute the function, but a waiting icon is displayed that never disappears.

[Add-In processes request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7hfS.jpg)

To explain the situation, I show function-file.js, functionfile (XPage that supplies html) and the manifest.xml.

**functionfile.xsp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:metaData name="charset" content="UTF-8"></xp:metaData>
        <xp:script
            src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
        <xp:linkResource href="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
            type="text/javascript">
        </xp:linkResource>
        <xp:linkResource
            href="node_modules/showdown/dist/showdown.min.js"
            type="text/javascript">
        </xp:linkResource>
        <xp:linkResource href="node_modules/urijs/src/URI.min.js"
            type="text/javascript">
        </xp:linkResource>
        <xp:linkResource href="function-file.js"
            type="text/javascript">
        </xp:linkResource>
    </xp:this.resources>

</xp:view>
```

**function-file.js**

```
var config;

Office.initialize = function () {
    //config = getConfig();
};

function showAddIn(event) {
    //alert("Show Add-In");
    event.completed();
    event = null;
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>7164e750-dc86-49c0-b548-1bac57abdc7c</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Stanoc GmbH</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Stanoc Add-In" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Ermöglicht die Archivsuche innerhalb von Outlook"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon32.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon64.png" />

  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Source/ARC/ARCS_40_DEDE_SRC.NSF/CWEB_CONTENT_XC_DIAE.xsp?Addin" />

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <!-- These elements support older clients that don't support add-in commands -->
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <!-- NOTE: Just reusing the read taskpane page that is invoked by the button
             on the ribbon in clients that support add-in commands. You can 
             use a completely different page if desired -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Source/ARC/ARCS_40_DEDE_SRC.NSF/CWEB_CONTENT_XC_DIAE.xsp?Addin"/>
        <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>

    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message read form -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />

                <!-- Function button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="green-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="green-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="green-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>showAddIn</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>

                <!-- Task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="configurationButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel2" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle2" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription2" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="green-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="green-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="green-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="configurationUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>

                </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="green-icon-16" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="green-icon-32" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="green-icon-80" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/assets/icon-80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Source/AP/AP_40_DEDE_SRC.NSF/functionfile.xsp" />
        <bt:Url id="readTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Source/ARC/ARCS_40_DEDE_SRC.NSF/CWEB_CONTENT_XC_DIAE.xsp?Addin" />
        <bt:Url id="configurationUrl" DefaultValue="https://mail.stanoc.com/conats/Dev/Samples/XPages/xScrapbook.nsf/Settings.xsp"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Stanoc Add-In" />
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Archivsuche" />
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel2" DefaultValue="Konfiguration" />

        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Zeige Archivsuche an" />
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle2" DefaultValue="Konfiguriere Archivsuche" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Hier können die Parameter für eine Archivsuche eingegeben und die Suche durchgeführt werden." />
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription2" DefaultValue="Hier kann das Login für die Archivsuche konfiguriert werden." />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

I have also tried to substitute the Xpage with normal HTML. No success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title></title>
    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/showdown/dist/showdown.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/urijs/src/URI.min.js"></script>
    <script src="function-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- NOTE: The body is empty on purpose. Since this is invoked via a button, there
     is no UI to render. -->
</body>
</html>
```

Help with code snippets is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We were able to successfully execute the function locally with your code so there seems to be nothing wrong with it. Can you double-check the url for your functionfile.xsp?